# How to fix 'Call to undefined function _get_custom_object_labels()'

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, undefined-function

Please help me, not sure how to fix it 'Call to undefined function _get_custom_object_labels()'

Code below:

```
);
$nohier_vs_hier_defaults['menu_name'] = $nohier_vs_hier_defaults['name'];

$labels = _get_custom_object_labels( $tax, $nohier_vs_hier_defaults );

$taxonomy = $tax->name;

$default_labels = clone $labels;

/**
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow :-) 
The code you have posted is incomplete. The error message tells you that the interpreter can not find the method _get_custom_object_labels. This means you are missing a file where the method is defined. Furthermore it is good practice to add the programming language as a tag to your question. I guess this is php?

See also this:

Comment: Hi, thank you :) Yes its php. Ok so how would I fix this issue, I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: I don't really fiddle with the coding side, I normally use page builders to build my websites.

Comment: You need to find the file where _get_custom_object_labels is defined. 
Do a fulltext seach on all your php files for `function _get_custom_object_labels`. 
Than you need to make this method callable from where you want to call it.

Comment: If you do not have basic php knowledge it will be hard to fix it for you, because you need to understand concepts like includes, classes, objects, scopes and access modifiers.

Comment: How would this issue even arise?

Comment: Is their any other way I could fix it?

Comment: A programmer thought that there will be a method available named _get_custom_object_labels. For some reason this method is not available. Maybe someone deleted it, because he or she thought it is no longer needed.

Comment: The site did crash when I was using the defender plugin, that did remove some things

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have updated your WordPress or some plugin has done it. try to downgrade your WordPress to the previous version.